# Rename XML Node Name in XML column SQL Server using SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-column

I have a Xml Column in a SQL Server 2012 database table called ValidationList. I have a few hundred records in this table.

I have a record like follows

```
<Configuration xmlns="blah">
  <CheckTest name="ValidationA">
    <TestName>NumericTest</TestName>
  </CheckTest>
</Configuration>
```

I need to Update all the rows and Rename the Node TestName to ValidationName, how can i do this in SQL script?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way just using `replace`:

```
update yourtable
set yourcolumn = 
       replace(cast(yourcolumn as nvarchar(max)), 'TestName', 'ValidationName');
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7da0/1)